# Web Links Scraping

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, data-science

I'm working on a project that requires me to web scrape unique links from a website and save them to a CSV file.  I've read through quite a bit of material for how to do this, I've watched videos, done trainings on Pluralsight and LinkedIn Learning and I mostly have this situation figured out there is one aspect of the assignment that I'm not sure how to do.

The program is supposed to scrape web links from both the Domain that is given (see code below) and any web links outside of the domain.

```
import bs4 as bs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

BASE_url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(BASE_url, "html.parser")

filename = "C996JamieCooperTask1.csv"
file = open(filename, "w")
headers = "WebLinks as of 4/7/2019\n"
file.write(headers)

all_Weblinks = soup.find_all('a')

url_set = set()

def clean_links(tags, base_url):
    cleaned_links = set()
    for tag in tags:
        link = tag.get('href')

        if link is None:
            continue

        if link.endswith('/') or link.endswith('#'):
            link = link[-1]

        full_urls = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, link)
        cleaned_links.add(full_urls)
    return cleaned_links

baseURL = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"

cleaned_links = clean_links(all_Weblinks, baseURL)

for link in cleaned_links:
    file.write(str(link) + '\n')

print ("URI's written to .CSV File")
```

The code works for all web links that are internal to the baseURL so that exist in that website but doesn't grab any that point external to the site.  I know the answer has to be something simple but after working on this project for some time I just can't see what is wrong with it so please help me.

Comment: Which external links are missing? I've skimmed through the web-page source code and haven't found any links to domains outside `census.gov`.

Comment: I'm not sure what links are missing I just know that when I submitted the assignment that they told me that external links were missing - ones outside of www.census.gov Domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a selector such as follows inside a set comprehension. This looks for `a` tag elements with `href` that starts with `http` or `/`. It is a starting point you can tailor. You would need more logic because there is at least one url which is simply `/` by itself.

```
links = {item['href'] for item in soup.select('a[href^=http], a[href^="/"]')}
```

Also, check that all expected urls are present in soup as I suspect some require javascript to run on page.

Comment: Yes it was sorry forgot to post that I figured it out, I had a couple of lines of code that were excluding any websites that were not on the same domain.  Thanks everybody for your help.  I passed the assignment and am moving on to my next course.